# Add print styles to HTML email for Gmail

Tags: html, printing, gmail, html-email

Is there some way force Gmail to use a set of styles when printing? The problem I'm running into is that it's stripping out my background images and background colors when I print. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So I had a feeling I knew the answer to this, and the answer is no. Gmail removes all background colors and images when you try to print and so far there doesn't appear to be a way to override this outside of Gmail's own settings.

Bonus points, Gmail strips out all `style` tags, though I've never heard a reasonable explanation as to why.

TL;DR: You can't give print styles to Gmail and Google 'knows better [sic]' than you.

Comment: Gmail doesn't strip all style tags, only the ones that refer to a user-defined class or ID. From what I've seen, it obeys styling for standard elements.